# C# Extract Specific Frame from WMV

Tags: c#, video-processing

[This example on Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/ExtractVideoFrames.aspx) is almost exactly what I need... except the `saveFrameFromVideo` takes a percentage instead of a frame number...

How can I use this to extract frame X from a WMV file?

I've also tried [FFmpeg.NET](http://ffmpegdotnet.codeplex.com/)... but there weren't any downloadable builds, and I couldn't get the source to build...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also try [**AsfMojo**](http://asfmojo.codeplex.com/) for this task, it allows you to extract an image by time offset:

```
Bitmap bitmap = AsfImage.FromFile(videoFileName)
                        .AtOffset(17.34);
```

Internally the Media SDK and some custom stream manipulation is used to get frame accurate still frames (up to a 100 millisecond tolerance), so if you know the frame rate of your media file (i.e. 25) you can calculate the time offset of the nearest frame:

```
int frameX = 400; //get 400th frame
double frameRate = 25.0;
double timeOffset = frameX / frameRate;

Bitmap bitmap = AsfImage.FromFile(videoFileName)
                        .AtOffset(timeOffset);
```

Comment: This is great! Is there any way to get it to work on DRM protected videos though?

Comment: @TheAdamGaskins: Unfortunately unless you are using Media Foundation (which AsfMojo is not) there currently is no way (to my knowledge) to extract images from DRM protected videos in C#, a summary of the problem is presented here: http://windowsmedianet.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Can AsfMojo parse AVI files?

Comment: Nope just ASF files, which is mostly WMV and WMA files

Answer (score 2):

The magic is in this line:

```
mediaDet.WriteBitmapBits(streamLength * percentagePosition, 
                    target.Width, target.Height, outputBitmapFile);
```

It's calculating the frame number from the percentage and the length of the stream. Since you already know the frame number, use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on extracting frames from webcam videos and video files- for both, i used  the AForge library- (you need to add references to AForge.Video, AForge.Imaging , AForge.Video.Directshow and AForge.Video.FFMPEG). For live videos, I added a videoSourcePlayer_NewFrame(object sender, ref Bitmap image) to get the frame- Bitmap image contains the required frame in type Bitmap. This is basically the event handler for the videosource player i added in the windows form.
For video from a file, i used:
videoSource=new FileVideoSoource(fileName);
videoSource.Start();
videoSource.NewFrame += new AForge.Video.NewFrameEventHandler(videoSource_NewFrame);

videoSource_NewFrame is the event handler in case there is a new frame.